# Laravel Route can't differentiate Get and Post

Tags: laravel, post, routes, get

I have a route like this:

```
Route::prefix('orders')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/countries', [OrderController::class, 'listCountry']);
    
    Route::get('/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'show']);
});
```

When I call Post method "example.com/api/orders/countries", i got an error message

```
Argument #1 ($id) must be of type int, string given
```

I guess Laravel call Get method instead of Post (using 'countries' as a parameter), is there any idea to fix this?
Full route list:

```
Route::prefix('orders')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/list', [OrderController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/list-by-cond', [OrderController::class, 'listByCond']);
    Route::post('/import', [OrderController::class, 'import']);
    Route::post('/', [OrderController::class, 'store']);

    Route::post('/countries', [OrderController::class, 'listCountry']);
    Route::post('/cities-by-country/{countryId}', [OrderController::class, 'listCityByCountry']);
    Route::post('/tags', [OrderController::class, 'Tags']);

    Route::get('/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'show']);
    Route::put('/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'delete']);
    Route::post('/close/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'close']);
});
```

Comment: add ``->where('id', '[0-9]+');`` to the get route.

Comment: though I doubt you're not calling the route via POST method !!

Comment: it should be "example.com/api/orders/countries". you're ignoring the prefix

Comment: it's "example.com/api/orders/countries", i've updated my question

Comment: did you clear the route cache? artisan route:clear?

Comment: i cleared many times

Comment: maybe another route overtakes the request. try the artisan route:list. maybe add the whole route file

Comment: i've updated my question with full route list

Comment: There is no problem with the route. Can you show us how you call post method?

Comment: @duc it's wrong `Route::post('/countries', [OrderController::class, 'listCountry']);` a `post` HTTP with method `listCountry` and on prefix `order`? Should be a `get`. Only prefix the `{id}` to the `resource` (best practices).

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these "best practice" routes for CRUD on `orders`:

```
GET: app/orders (orders.index) //list
POST: app/orders (orders.store)
GET: app/orders/create (orders.create) //show form create
GET: app/orders/{id} (orders.show) //show order ID
PATCH: app/orders/{id} (orders.update) // or PUT
DELETE: app/orders/{id} (orders.destroy)
GET: app/orders/{id}/edit (orders.edit) //show form edit
```

My suggestion is to:

- On the routes that have `listBy..` method you need to use query params like `app/orders?cond=XYZ`, and use it on `GET` on the `index` method.
- For `countries` do a separate prefix for routes crud, or if you want to list do query param on the list of orders.
- Do a different prefix for `TAGS` crud. `//don't know what tags method do`
- Do routes like `{id}/close`, `{id}/import` for orders.

You can see more on laravel [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-controllers).